# Limits of sets question

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $A_n \rightarrow A$.  Where convergence is defined in a usual way as:
\begin{align}
\limsup A_n=\bigcap_{n}\bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k=\liminf A_n=\bigcup_{n}\bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k
\end{align}

My question is the following if $A_n \rightarrow A$ does it imply that  $A_n^c \rightarrow A^c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\bigcap_{n}\bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k=\bigcup_{n}\bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k
\end{align}

then

\begin{align}
(\bigcap_{n}\bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k)^c=(\bigcup_{n}\bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k)^c
\end{align}

then
\begin{align}
\bigcup_{n}\bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k^c = \bigcap_{n}\bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k^c
\end{align}

Comment: Seriously, how didn't I see this.

Comment: @Alex I also asked myself this question many times. It does happen, luckily not too often, to everyone

Answer (score 2):

$$\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k^c=\bigcap_n\left(\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_n\right)^c=\left(\bigcup_n\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_n\right)^c$$
$$\bigcup_n\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k^c=\bigcup_n\left(\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_n\right)^c=\left(\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_n\right)^c$$
Hence $\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_n=\bigcup_n\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_n$ implies $\left(\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_n\right)^c=\left(\bigcup_n\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_n\right)^c$ and hence
$$\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k^c=\bigcup_n\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k^c$$